# Default seeds in Stata

Tags: stata

I gather from [the Stata manual on the RNG seed](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rsetseed.pdf) that the value for the `seed` is 123456789 every time Stata is launched. My questions are

1. Was it always this way or was the default `seed` different in older versions (I'm particularly concerned with version 8)
2. Is the default `sortseed` also 123456789?

Comment: If you go back far enough, the generator was different, and so a difference of seed becomes immaterial. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?version has some details.

Comment: If I think I need to use `sortseed`, I need to stop myself and remember that that is a sure sign that there is a problem in my code that I need to solve. Using `sortseed` just hides the symptoms of a bug, which is obviously a very bad thing. [Here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2005-09/msg00582.html) is an explanation for that position.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I'm fully aware that there's a big "here be dragons" sign right next to `set sortseed`. But my aim here isn't to paper over one of my own programming snafus but to replicate someone else's work. And that work does seem to be sensitive to a sort. What I want is to be able to do is to find the `sortseed` under which the original results, which I cannot replicate even with the original do-file, obtain and then to show that they depend directly on that `sortseed`. There are other ways to make that point but doing it via the `sortseed` seems the simplest to understand.

Comment: @NickCox I have access to the actual old versions of Stata, but I still don't know what the default `sortseed` is in those versions.

Comment: I'd go straight to Stata tech support on this. I am not sure that default seeds were documented in early versions.

Comment: @NickCox Cheers! I've shot them an email and will report back here if I get an answer that might be helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own questions:

Going back to at least version 8 the default `seed` was `123456789` but as Nick Cox points out in comments above this doesn't mean all versions of Stata would produce the same sequence of random numbers based on that seed because the random number generator has changed over time.

The default sortseed seems to be `1001`:

```
. query sortseed
. di r(sortseed)
1001
```